# Replacement with vectors

Tags: r, replace

I have a vector with all consonants and I want every single consonant to be replaced with a "C" in a given data frame. Assume my data frame is x below:

```
   x <- c("abacate", "papel", "importante")

    v <- c("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")
    c <- c("b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y",     "z")

    find    <- c
    replace <- "C"
    found   <- match(x, find)

    ifelse(is.na(found), x, replace[found])
```

This is not working. Could anybody tell me what the problem is and how I can fix it?

Thanks

Comment: try to avoid using `c` as a variable name. It is the name of a very important function in `R`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions (`gsub`) are far more flexible in general, but for that particular problem you can also use the `chartr` function which will run faster:

```
old <- c("b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n",
         "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z")
new <- rep("C", length(old))
chartr(paste(old, collapse = ""),
       paste(new, collapse = ""), x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `gsub` to replace the letters in a character vector:

```
c <- c("b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y",     "z")
consonants = paste(c("[", c, "]"), collapse="")
replaced = gsub(consonants, "C", x)
```

`consonants` becomes a regular expression, `[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]`, that means "any letter inside the brackets."

One of the reasons your code wasn't working is that `match` doesn't look for strings within other strings, it only looks for exact matches. For example:

```
> match(c("a", "b"), "a")
[1]  1 NA
> match(c("a", "b"), "apple")
[1] NA NA
```

Comment: The function to look for strings inside strings is `gregexpr`. Usually followed by `regmatches` to do the relacements. But it takes a single pattern at a time so you would have to loop... `gsub` or `chartr` are much better approaches.